# Python Button Options

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram

I would like to add custom buttons like the following into my telegram bot message, but I have no idea how to embed them into my message with Python

[image]

I would like to embed it into this message

```
def run(results, index, msgText):
# The message below this!
    msg = '<b>Hello there, ' + results[index]['message']['from']['username'] + '!</b> I am <b>Makuna Hattata</b>, a spin-off bot of the original <b>Hakuna Mattata</b> bot  \n\nI am a semi-smart bot capable of understanding basic commands, which you can see by pressing the button below!' 
    try:
        sendMessage(index, results, msg, '&parse_mode=html')
        logWorked(results[index]['message']['from']['username'], results[index]['message']['from']['id'], "/start message sent")
    except Exception as err:
        logError(results[index  ]['message']['from']['username'], results[index]['message']['from']['id'], "/start message sent", err)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply send a custom keyboard. First you need the `telegram` [api](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot). You can always use the `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` [command](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardmarkup). It will look something like this:

```
keyboard = [["key1", "key2"], ["return"]]
reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup.create(keyboard)
bot.send_message(user_id, 'testing keyboard', reply_markup=reply_markup)
```

If you DON'T want to import anything additional (which actually would give you a lot of tools to work with if you do!) you can use the following function:

```
def send_keyboard(token, chat_id, text, keyboard=[], one_time=True, resize=True):

    if text is None or len(text) <= 0:
        return None

    post_data = {
        "chat_id": chat_id,
        "text": text
    }

    if len(keyboard) == 0:
        return None

    post_data["reply_markup"] = {
        "keyboard": keyboard,
        "one_time_keyboard": one_time,
        "resize_keyboard": resize
    }

    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Content-Length": len(json.dumps(post_data))
    }

    url = TELEGRAM_HOSTNAME + "/bot" + token + "/sendMessage"
    try:
        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(post_data))
    except:
        return None

    if response.status_code >= 400:
        return None

    return response
```

And you just got to give it the chat_id, the token, the message text and the keys for the keyboard.

Comment: Any way of doing it without an api? I am trying to not use an API.

Comment: I added some code, check it out, see if it solves your issue.

Comment: So, shortened, I send it in a `reply_markup` parameter to the sendmessage?